# What is "assumed-role" in my AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I log into my company's AWS Cloud, my account at the upper-right corner of the AWS web console looks like this

```
assumed-role/MyCompany-AWS2381845957-Developer/my.name@example.com
```

What does it mean? Is it a root user account, or am I logged in as an IAM user? Have I "assumed a role"? My account has restrictions, for example I can't create new IAM users, so I can't be the root user. But at the same time I login with my ID and password, not with public/private keys like an IAM user.

Also, my account is listed under "Federated Login", and I had seen somewhere that it uses a "SAML provider".

Comment: How do you login to AWS? Do you use the [official console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?#) or does you company have a Single Sign-On system?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I login from a URL on my own company's domain. I think it is a Single Sign-On, because we use a SAML provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your company maintains the identity provider (IdP) and the username "my.name@example.com" is maintained there.

So when you are logging in, you are "assuming" an IAM Role named "MyCompany-AWS2381845957-Developer" and you will have the permission which is attached to this role. This IAM Role and the SAML provider are mapped in your company's IdP.

Also, to clarify, IAM user logs in using username and password (and MFA token), not with public/private keys. However, they can interact with AWS API using access keys.

- [Identity Providers and Federation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers.html)
- [Access Keys (Access Key ID and Secret Access Key)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys)